# How to install and run Puppet Device in order to configure Cisco Switches and Routers?

Tags: cisco, router, puppet, switch

According to [this documentation](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/puppet-network-device-management) it should be possible to configure a Cisco Switch by using the Puppet Module Device.

Where could this module be found?

Is this module restricted to Puppet Enterprise?

How to install it and run it in order to configure Cisco Switches?

Consulted sources:

- [source1](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/puppet-network-device-management)
- [source2](http://puppetlabs.com/blog/puppet-network-device-management)
- [source3](http://www.slideshare.net/getyourbuildon/cisco-automation-with-puppet-and-onepk)
- [source4](http://www.scottyob.com/2012/12/08/my-experiences-of-managing-a-cisco-switch-with-puppet/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing additional to install. On a node you configure /etc/puppet/device.conf with your switch information and then run `puppet device` on that node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try this tomorrow or next week (the switches are located on my work) and let you know the outcome.

Comment: `puppet device -d` results in `Error: Can't load cisco for device1: Connecting with ssh to a network device req
uires the 'net/ssh' ruby library` on both `Windows` as `Linux`. `puppet --version` => `3.6.2`. After installing this library by executing `gem install net-ssh` the error persists.

Comment: [Puppet issue has been created](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2915)